# How to prevent the Facebook Application to ask any permission?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, permissions, facebook-apps

I have a facebook App and it works.
But when users go to the app page it try to do access users base information. It asks
permission(just first time). Be able to see anyone without any question.

I wanted to make an example of this is the appropriate:

```
https://www.facebook.com/GKFXPhilippines/app_155718427915844
```

I don't want to come out the following screen;

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a genuinely bad idea. That permission check is there for a reason. Why do you want to access user's information without them knowing it?

Comment: I don't want to access, I just want to show them my app. My app is a form application.

Comment: if it's just a basic app then the permissions dialogue shouldn't show unless you are trying to ask for data that you need permission for so I'd have a look in your code to see if your asking for any anywhere or double check your app settings. Also, it didn't ask me for permissions.

Comment: @nermik OK, it seems I misunderstood your question: I read it as if you wanted to access user's data without asking permission.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/GKFXPhilippines/app_155718427915844 this is an example which I want to do. It is not my app.

Answer (score 2):

I used MVC;
in controller page had default this line:

```
[FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
```

I removed them and solved my problem.